# Beating Cthulhu in Magicka

Tags: magicka

A friend and I are fighting against Cthulhu since last month, and still we're not able to kill him!

We're both using the tron-like mage, and always trying to cast lightings against the water (saw a youtube video explaining it) to max out the damage to the boss, but it doesn't seem to affect him that much. We're out of ideas, we tried everything we could but eventually we end up dying with the boss at 50% health after a 30 minute long fight with minor but continuous damage to him... and this doesn't feel like the right way to do it!

We wanted to try everything we could before asking, but now it's become annoying (well, it became after 1 week of useless tryouts) so we have to ask for help to all the magickans outside! Any help/advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By far the easiest way is to use [Propp's Party Plasma](https://magicka.gamepedia.com/Propp%27s_Party_Plasma) (a beefed-up version of the spell that sent you basementward during the prologue of the original campaign), you should be able to solo Cthulhu in 30 seconds using it.

If you don't wish to use the cheap method, you can do what I did:

- Stay in contact with voice chat (Pretty much a requirement for enjoying Magicka)
- Cast wall shield when he tries to suck you up
- Stay near but not in the middle of the platform, to prevent getting confused
- Use the lightning death ray spell (steam - steam - lightning - lightning - arcane) to inflict damage
- Shield when he fires purple insta-kill projectiles.
- Don't panic if you get grabbed by the tentacles, you are actually pretty safe to heal, shield up and revive any fallen friends.
- Cast shield - water - frost (ice shield) to give yourself some staying power.
- Hold RMB when you're moved towards the water, it will stop you from moving, wait it out until the purple halo around your head disappears.

If all else fails and you have people to spare, a wizard maintaining a bubble shield ready to cast revive at a moment's notice is always helpful.

Comment: sorry for late accepting the answer, this worked (finally)... too bad i corrupted my installation while playing with a friend, i have to do it back again from the beginning :(

Answer (score 1):

Hey I would try a realy simple tactic shield all of his tentacle attacks and damage him then. Repeat till he is dead ^^

[As shown in this Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVGW9MR_LL0)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best magic to attack Cthulhu is QFQFQFAS(Steam-Steam-Steam-Lighting-Arcane)
That magic can damage 4500!

Answer (score 0):

A-S-S-S-S can do up to 6000 damage, if you let one of the frog creatures alive he wont spawn the big guy when he is low on hp, plus, throw rocks at his mouth when he sucks you to make him stop, don't stay close to the center nor far from it so you wont get in reach of the tentacles.